# How to set Travis to fail when I don't pass my pylint threshold

Tags: travis-ci, pylint, pylintrc

Say I run my pylint suite and get a score of 9.2/10. I want this to be deemed acceptable by Travis as above a 9/10 cutoff, and allow for a successful build.

Now someone else commits to the same repository with poorly formatted code, generating a new pylint score of 8.9/10. I want Travis to fail on this.

What can I add to my pylint.rc to allow for this behavior? 
Even just having pylint exit with a non-success when below that threshold of 9/10 would be enough to get started.

Comment: Post your Travis ci config file here

Comment: I have just added pylint support to https://github.com/exussum12/coverageChecker  you need php installed on your ci server, but that can use the diff and say 90% of the differnce must pass pylint for example

Comment: Awesome, I find a lot of use from that feature.